# What's the difference of EventStream and EventBus

Tags: c#, events, system.reactive, event-bus

I was wondering if there is any difference between EventBus and EventStream or are the two just synonyms?
Or is a EventStream just a layer above the EventBus that allows to filter, transform, etc. the events?

Comment: Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bus_(computing) and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_(computing) - they are distinctly different things.

Answer (score 0):

My quick differentiation would be that one is a centralized and the other is topic/endpoint. i.e. if your system used an Event Bus (Enterprise Service Bus?) then each component would subscribe to the centralized Bus to get messages. However if I was to use an EventStream, I would expect to subscribe to a decentralized endpoint specific for the events I am subscribing to.